# Symfony : a form field does not want to be null dispite the constraints

Tags: forms, symfony

In my entity Transaction, the field credit is nullable. [field credit in entity Transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yuuT.png)
In my transactionType,I wrote for the chield credit, the option required at false.
[the chield credit in transactionType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIFM3.png)
But when I submit the form, a message asks me to fill in the field.

I tried changing the attribute in the entity, and the constraint in the form but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `empty_data => null` ([IntegerType doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/integer.html#empty-data)). You should post as code instead of screenshots btw. You should edit your question.

Comment: Ok. It's my fault. I put false between quotes in 'required' => false. Thank you for your help.